Cisco Anyconnect V 4.10 : Split Tunnel not Working
I have tried this on both Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.10, but in neither case the split-tunnel configuration doesn't work with Cisco Anyconnect VPN. Anyconnect uses 2FA making it difficult to use openconnect.
On debian 12.5 the same configuration works, so it's not the VPN server that's causing the issue, but something specific to Ubuntu. I don't know where to begin troubleshooting. Grateful for any advice or suggestions.

You weren't specific with details; you do mention releases (22.04 & 23.10) but I wonder what product (Server? Desktop?) and what kernel stack, as HWE on 22.04 is the same 6.5 as used by 23.10; but GA kernel is older (5.15) like your Debian 12.5 (6.1) that works... so did you explore what you were actually running, rather than just the release detail.  Don't forget 22.04 is a LTS thus has kernel stack choice (default set by install media used)
